# Recursively merge pdf's in subfolders using the pyPDF2 module in python

Tags: python, pypdf

Im a novice developer learning python and .Im trying to recursively parse folders and subfolders conatining multiple pdf's and merging them into one pdf based on the subfolder name.
I have the following folder and subfolder structure

folder before merger

```
dummy
           ball
               ball_baseball.pdf
               ball_basketball.pdf
               ball_volleyball.pdf
          ice
               ice_skating.pdf
               ice_curling.pdf
               ice_hockey.pdf
```

The ideal result that id like to see is

```
       dummy
           ball
               ball.pdf(containing 3 sheets)
           ice
               ice.pdf (containing 3 sheets)
```

There is question string previous answered for csv files using pandas .but im using PyPDf for merging the pdf'f
Here is the code I have tried so far.
It seems to work but imay have messed up the for loop so recursively appends and merges pdf's in the subfolder

```
import sys, os,PyPDf2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
dirs=r"path to the folder directory"
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(dirs):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filepath, 'rb')))
            merger.write(str(filename))`
```

Any advise will be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have figured how to run them in a loop

```
rootDir=r"path to your directory"
for dirName,subDir, fileList in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=False):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for fname in fileList:
        merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(dirName, fname),'rb')))
merger.write(str(dirName)+".pdf")
```

bringing the merger= PdfMerger() inside the loop did the trick !!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite an old question but i had the same problem myself. I tried the solution by C. Taylor but I ended up with some errors. Anyways for following code worked for me.

```
import sys, os,PyPDf2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
print("testing ")

hdir=os.getcwd()
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(hdir):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()    
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            print(filename)
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filepath, 'rb')))
    merger.write(os.path.join(hdir,os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(root))+'.pdf'))
```

The merged PDFs had the name of their folder and it was written to the main dir.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the merged files to be written to the folder containing your python script rather than the subfolder, you'd need to make a couple of tweaks:

```
import sys, os,PyPDf2

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
hdir=r #path to the folder directory; would suggest using os.getcwd()
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(hdir):
#changed so that directories thrown by os.walk are not the same as start
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for dir in dirs:
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filepath, 'rb')))
                #merger.write(str(filename))
        merger.write(os.path.join(hdir,dir+'.pdf'))
        #writes to the main directory, names the merged file after the subdirectory
```

Comment: To write to the subfolder, change `os.path.join(hdir` to `os.path.join(root`.

Comment: C.Taylor .I have tried your code and Im getting this error   ` merger.write(os.path.join(root,dirs+'.pdf'))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`    when i tried the the code I posted with changing directory variable ,istill get the same result .If I have 4 single pages pdf's in a subfolder the fourth pdf ballons upto 10 pages as it is recursively appending all the pages.

Comment: My error was thinking that dirs was a directory instead of a list. I have edited the code above to change that.

Comment: How do you name the file that was merged not the subdirectory name but something like "results.pdf"?