# trying to reference Qlistwidget and got "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ListWidget" error instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pypdf

i'm new to programming and have been trying to learn python for these past few week. i stumble upon [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFxZ3SerLoo&t=2225s)  video and tried to make similiar thing but i want to add new feature where i can batch merge all the sub folder pdf into their own pdf. after adding the path to the folder and adding new method i got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745268/recursively-merge-pdfs-in-subfolders-using-the-pypdf2-module-in-python) user i got an error saying that list widget isn't str.

```
import sys, os
if hasattr(sys, 'frozen') :
    os.environ['path'] = sys.MEIPASS + ";" + os.environ['path']
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QListWidget, \
    QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, \
    QDialog, QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QAbstractItemView
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger, PdfReader


def resource_path(relative_path) :
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception :
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

class ListWidget(QListWidget) :
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setStyleSheet('''font-size: 25px;''')
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event) :
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            return super().dragEnterEvent(event)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            return super().dragMoveEvent(event)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            
            pdfFiles=[]
            
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                if url.isLocalFile():
                    if url.toString().endswith('.pdf'):
                        pdfFiles.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))
            self.addItems(pdfFiles)
        else:
            return super().dropEvent(event)
        
class output_field(QLineEdit) :
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.height = 55
        self.setStyleSheet('font-size: 30px;')
        self.setFixedHeight(self.height)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event) :
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            
            if event.mimeData().urls():
                self.setText(event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile())

        else:
            event.ignore()

class output_field(QLineEdit) :
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.height = 55
        self.setStyleSheet('font-size: 30px;')
        self.setFixedHeight(self.height)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event) :
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            
            if event.mimeData().urls():
                self.setText(event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile())

        else:
            event.ignore()

class button(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, label_text):
        super().__init__()
        self.setText(label_text)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 180px;
            height: 50px;
        ''')   

class PDFApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('PDF FILE MERGE')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(resource_path('alice.ico')))
        self.resize(1800, 800)
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        outputFolderROw = QHBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.outputFIle = output_field()
        outputFolderROw.addWidget(self.outputFIle)

        self.buttonBrowseOutputFile = button('&save to')
        self.buttonBrowseOutputFile.clicked.connect(self.populateFileName)
        outputFolderROw.addWidget(self.buttonBrowseOutputFile)

    def initUI(self):
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        outputFolderROw = QHBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.outputFIle = output_field()
        outputFolderROw.addWidget(self.outputFIle)

        self.buttonBrowseOutputFile = button('&save to')
        self.buttonBrowseOutputFile.clicked.connect(self.populateFileName)
        outputFolderROw.addWidget(self.buttonBrowseOutputFile)
        """
        # listbox widget
        """
    
        self.pdfListWidget = ListWidget(self)
        """
        Buttons
        """
        self.buttonBrowseinputFile =button('&Folder')
        self.buttonBrowseinputFile.clicked.connect(self.addFolderPath)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBrowseinputFile)

        self.buttonDeleteSelect =button('&Delete')
        self.buttonDeleteSelect.clicked.connect(self.deleteSelected)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.buttonDeleteSelect)

        self.buttonMerge = button('&merge')
        self.buttonMerge.clicked.connect(self.mergeFile)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.buttonMerge)

        self.buttonBatchMerge = button('&batch merge')
        self.buttonBatchMerge.clicked.connect(self.batch_merge)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBatchMerge)

        self.buttonClose = button('&close')
        self.buttonClose.clicked.connect(QApplication.quit)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.buttonClose)

        self.buttonReset = button('&Reset')
        self.buttonReset.clicked.connect(self.clearQueue)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.buttonReset)

        mainLayout.addLayout(outputFolderROw)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pdfListWidget)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def deleteSelected(self):
        for item in self.pdfListWidget.selectedItems():
            self.pdfListWidget.takeItem(self.pdfListWidget.row(item))

    def addFolderPath(self):
        add_folder_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'addfolder',os.getcwd())
        return self.pdfListWidget.addItem(str(add_folder_path))
    
    def clearQueue(self):
        self.pdfListWidget.clear()
        self.outputFIle.setText('')

    def dialogMessage(self, message):
        dig = QMessageBox(self)
        dig.setWindowTitle('PDF Manager')
        dig.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        dig.setText(message)
        dig.show()

    def _getSaveFilePath(self):
        file_save_path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save PDF file', os.getcwd(), 'pdf file(*.pdf)')
        return file_save_path
    
    def populateFileName(self):
        path = self._getSaveFilePath()
        if path:
            self.outputFIle.setText(path)

    def mergeFile(self):
        if not self.outputFIle.text():
            self.populateFileName()
            return
        
        if self.pdfListWidget.count() > 0:
            pdfMerger = PdfMerger()

            try:
                for i in range(self.pdfListWidget.count()):
                    pdfMerger.append(self.pdfListWidget.item(i).text())

                pdfMerger.write(self.outputFIle.text())
                self.dialogMessage('pdf merge complete')

            except Exception as e:
                self.dialogMessage(e)
        else:
            self.dialogMessage('Queue is empty')

    def batch_merge(self):  #the error happen here when i click the button
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(self.pdfListWidget): #dirs didn't get referenced for some reason
            merger = PdfMerger()    
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                merger.append(PdfReader(open(filepath, 'rb')))
        merger.write(os.path.join(self.pdfListWidget,os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(root))+'.pdf'))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('fusion')

pdfApp = PDFApp()
pdfApp.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
def batch_merge(self): 
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(self.pdfListWidget.item().text()): #adding text for some but the path still not referenced
            merger = PdfMerger()    
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                merger.append(PdfReader(open(filepath, 'rb')))
        merger.write(os.path.join(self.pdfListWidget.item().text(),os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(root))+'.pdf'))
```

i tried to add self.pdfListWidget.item().text() to make it like a str but got another error

```
File "c:\Users\fahmi\OneDrive\Desktop\pdf merge\pdf merge 5.py", line 245, in batch_merge
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(self.pdfListWidget.item().text()): #dirs didn't get referenced for some reason
TypeError: item(self, row: int): not enough arguments
```

are there anyway to append the listwidget list into the os.walk method?

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Comment: On what item of the list widget should `batch_merge` take action? What if you drop two directories?

Comment: the one with list of array on it :
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            
            pdfFiles=[]
            
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                if url.isLocalFile():
                    if url.toString().endswith('.pdf'):
                        pdfFiles.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))
            self.addItems(pdfFiles)